# What causes connection abort?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

On iPhone, sometimes when I open the app, all immediate HttpClient requests fail. I saw a message that said...

> Software caused connection abort

Upon retrying, there's no problem.

What could cause this?

It happens when the app is first opened on iPhone and Android and when the app is opened from clicking on a notification. In both of these situations a web request is sent immediately.

Is it possible that the connection is not ready yet and, rather than waiting, it's throwing an exception?

Comment: Without any code this is impossible to say

Comment: You think it could be the result of my code?

Comment: @IanWarburton Without any code and more info on the state of the app, it would be hard to say, but I could *assume* that if the app was running and placed into the background and then brought back, you are getting retry timeouts from not cancelling requests when the app was placed into the background (seen this a million times in apps) .... but that is just a wild swing... again, more app info needed....

Comment: @SushiHangover You're supposed to cancel requests when an app is backgrounded?

Comment: @IanWarburton When an app moves into a background state, execution is paused and there are lifecycle events to that commutate to you this is happening, you then have X amount of time to perform code cleanup. So things like in-flight HttpClient requests should be cancelled and and cached if needed to be retried upon the app resuming, i.e. as a "rule of thumb", any Task-based based should be cancelled via the cancellation token you provided to that Task (there are exceptions to this depending upon the OS and how the app is registered, ie. Android foregrounded Service, IOS VoIP app, etc... )

Comment: @SushiHangover When opening an app, is it possible that a connection could not be ready in time to run an immediately triggered request?

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar problem today!
I added an `await Task.Delay(200);` before launching the httprequest (only when app was launched  from notification tap) and the issue is fixed.

Comment: I added request retries using https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly. It doesn't always error so it seems a shame to always delay.

Comment: @IanWarburton, this issue keeps happening on a few Samsung Galaxy phone to one of my Xamarin app even we have polly retry in place.

Comment: @Prashant, does the task.Delay(200) always work for you?

Comment: @KevinHu Never faced it again after implementing that.

Comment: @PrashantGupta. Thanks for confirming that with me.